# Error not thrown while executing query

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, vb.net, casting

We executed below SQL command using  `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand`  and assigned to Sqldata reader.

```
SELECT DISTINCT cast([reg].[pin]  as float) AS [pin] FROM [reg]
```

Here datatype of column 'pin' is nvarchar and it contains some string data also. While executing query no error is thrown and also  reader `hasrows` property returned false, but when `reader.read` is done error is thrown.

Normally if query contains error while executing itself error will be thrown, but above query why is it behaving differently?

Comment: post your code for `reader`

Answer (score 0):

because sql thinks that everything will be fine at the first instance. When it reads data and tried to parse read  during  reader.read the error will be thrown.

Comment: thank u for the reply. But in above case hasrows returns 0.But how it can return 0 without processing the data in column?

Comment: Has rows just checks (queries db), if or not the reader will return any data.

Comment: Yes.Hasrows is boolean. But how hasrows will now whether data will be there or not without processing data.In my query without accessing pin column how it will now that select will return rows or not?

Comment: it will check the database and read if or not there are any rows to read. therefore it knows. but it will not move the cursor on to the next row.